# Installer for Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, netbeans, installation, ireport

I am developing an inventory system i-e a java desktop application. I am using Ms Access as database engine and there are certain modules e.g one makes reports using ireport and other such dependencies. I need to ask how can I make installer for my application which will install few fonts, copy database files, install jre to make it run etc. Please guide me in it.
Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've briefly used in the past, and it may serve your needs. It's an open source installer builder system, tailored towards Java apps.

http://izpack.org/

Comment: it work like a charm - and you can have offers you different configuration options for different OS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I've used jsmooth which creates a single EXE-file that unpacks and run transparently.  Not a full installer but worked well for us.

Note: I have not seen any Java installers which asks the "There is an update available. Update now?" question.

If this is important to you, then consider Java WebStart which checks for updates at each launch (but do not ask).